# Array of objects with nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

i've got the following array of objects

```
let prova: ActiveRoute[] = [
{
    path: '/Root',
    method: 'GET',
    children: [
        {
            path: '/Son',
            method: 'GET',
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/Grandson',
                    method: 'GET',
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: '/Boh',
                            method: 'GET',
                            activeMessage: 'End',
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    middleware: [
        'middleware1',
    ],
}
```

This is the ActiveRoute interface

```
export interface  ActiveRoute {
   path: string;
   children?: ActiveRoute[];
   middleware?: string[];
   method?: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
   activeMessage?: string;
```

}

I want to print all the path properties in a string.
What should i do?

This is what i've done (wrong)

```
function getEndPoints(prova) {
let endpoints: string = '';
prova.forEach((r) => {
    if (r.path) {
        endpoints += r.path;
        if(r.children){
            r.children.forEach((s) => {
                if (s.path) {
                    endpoints += s.path;
                }
                if (s.children){
                    s.children.forEach((z) =>{
                        if (z.path){
                            endpoints += z.path;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
console.log(endpoints);
```

}

I really don't understand how should i loop continuously and deeply within an array of objects.
This is my desire output, in this case: '/Root/Son/Grandson/Boh'.

Obviously now i don't how i'll go deep within.

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: Sure, i forgot to add it

Comment: While you are adding things, add the desired _output_ from the collection you've entered.

Comment: desire output: `/Root/Son/Grandson/Boh`  What if you have multiple children on any of the levels?.

Comment: I corrected the post.

Comment: Recursion is the key word here. You need a function that prints path and method of a "node" (argument of the function) and if that node has children, the function should call itself with the children as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input structure could have multiple results,..

eg. below I've modified so that `/Grandson` has multiple children.

```js
let prova = [
{
    path: '/Root',
    method: 'GET',
    children: [
        {
            path: '/Son',
            method: 'GET',
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/Grandson',
                    method: 'GET',
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: '/Boh',
                            method: 'GET',
                            activeMessage: 'End',
                        },
                        {
                            path: '/AnotherBoh',
                            method: 'GET',
                            activeMessage: 'End',
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    middleware: [
        'middleware1',
    ]
}];

function getLinks(p) {
  const arr = [];
  function inner(p, root) {
    p.forEach((x) => {
      const newroot = root + x.path;
      if (!x.children) {
        arr.push(newroot);
      } else {
        inner(x.children, newroot);
      }
    });
  }
  inner(p, "");
  return arr;
}

console.log(getLinks(prova));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i didn't think about recursion

Comment: Recursion should leap to your mind when you see a structure like this.  It's really the only technique that will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility, based on @Keith's answer, but which returns the list of paths as an array of strings rather than logging them.

```js
let prova = [{
    path: '/Root',
    children: [{
        path: '/Son',
        children: [{
            path: '/Grandson',
            children: [{
                path: '/Boh',
            }, {
                path: '/AnotherBoh',
                children: [{
                   path: '/Foo'
                }, {
                  path: '/Bar'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        path: '/AnotherSon',
    }],
    middleware: ['middleware1']
}];

function getPaths(p, base = "", gather = []) {
  return p.map((node) => {
    if (node.children) {
      getPaths(node.children, base + node.path, gather);
    } else {
      gather.push(base + node.path);
    }
    return gather
  }).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []); // removes an (unnecessary?) level of nesting
}

console.log(getPaths(prova));
```

Note that I removed a number of irrelevant properties, but added nesting at several levels, just to test.

---

### Update

Here's a cleaner version of the same idea:

```
const flat = arr => arr.reduce((out, item) => out.concat(item), [])

const getPaths = (p, base = "", gather = []) => flat(p.map((node) => ('children' in node) 
    ? getPaths(node.children, base + node.path, gather)
    : gather.concat(base + node.path)
))
```

Comment: `but which returns the list of paths`  Good point, I've altered mine to return an array too, as in real life would be much more useful.

Comment: Yes, it looks as though ours our quite similar now.  I think I like your inner function better than my `gather` parameter and final flattening step.  But I definitely prefer a `map` to a `forEach`.